# Prototype vs function definition

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Say I have the following Function

```
function FooController (){
  this.foo = function () {
    alert('foo');
  }
}

FooController.prototype.bar = function () {
  alert('bar');
}
```

Is there a difference between these two syntaxes? Why would I use one over the other? Is there a performance hit?

Comment: this just has to be a duplicate...

Comment: 1. yes, there's a diff, but it might be invisible depending on how you use instances. 2. it's complicated, know your options. 3. no, these days engines recycle function objects internally anyway, so the perf diff is minimal.

Comment: all instances of object X will have the function you defined under the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's defined on the prototype, any instance of FooController will "inherit" the `bar` method because it's in the instance's prototype chain. Only 1 function is defined and in memory using this technique.

If you define using `this.foo = function`, you're adding the function directly to the instance as a property of that instance. This means that you will have 1 function in memory per instance of the controller.

```
function FooController {}

FooController.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log("world");
};
```

Create an instance and check the prototype's value

```
var c = new FooController();
c.hello(); // "world"
```

This is as expected, but let's define a `hello` method directly on the `c` instance

```
c.hello = function() { console.log("cats"); };
c.hello(); // "cats"
```

We can still call the prototype method directly

```
c.prototype.hello.call(c); // "world"
```

Or we can `delete` the `hello` property on the `c` instance

```
delete c.hello;
```

Now let's call our function again

```
c.hello; // "world"
```

It's back to using the prototype's method !

Comment: these days engines recycle function objects internally, which the ES3 spec allows, so having "1 function in memory per instance" is not always the case like it would be with C or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

All instances of FooController will share `bar`, each `foo` will be created individually per object.

In general you want properties to be created with the `this.` syntax, so they're not shared, and functions to be created using the prototype syntax (there's no point in many identical functions)

You can run into trouble if you put functions on the prototypes.  With primitives you won't notice the difference, since writing to them will write to the local object and ignore the protoype, but you can cause problems with arrays like this.

```
function FooController (){
  this.foo = function () {
    alert('foo');
  }
}

FooController.prototype.bar = [];

var a = new FooController();
var b = new FooController();

a.bar.push['hi'];

alert(b.bar.length); //1
```

Comment: another highly significant advantage of the `this.foo = ` method is that `foo` then has access to the "private" lexically scoped variables inside `FooController`.  A prototype method cannot do that.

Comment: true.  I stopped writing when the question got closed :)